# symfony 1.4 & doctrine 1.2 - one model for a few tables

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I am using Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine 1.2 (MySQL) as ORM and have some problems.
The project is realy big and there are too many parameters that must be saved.

I have one table DataFlow and now i have 3Gb of new data to store in it per month.
I know about mysql partitions... but it is not very useful.

it was decided to store data in tables like ataFlow_2013_01 , DataFlow_2013_02 ..... that have same structure.

is it possible to create one model for interacting with tables DataFlow* and dynamically change table name in it? One of the reasons - final code must be compiled and obfuscated... so i cann`t create models dynamically  when new table is creating.

if you know how to do that or where i can read about that please help.

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the base classes of your generated model. Each model class has a function `setTableName()` which is called inside `setTableDefinition()`.

You can override this function with something like this:

```
public function setTableDefinition()
{
    parent::setTableDefinition();

    $this->setTableName('DataFlow_'.date('Y_m'));
}
```